# AngularStrap date-picker make good date range flow

Tags: datepicker, angular-strap

I really can't find any example of adding directive that uses the $datepicker service.

I'm trying to get the following functionality:

got 2 date pickers one bound to a fromDate field the other to toDate field. 
I want the toField datepicker to be opened automatically when the fromDate is closed.

I think that directive on one of the input fields is a good solution but i couldnt find any clean way to listen to the datepicker state.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Well it's easier than looks, just documentation is not so good:

here is a simple solution:

on the from date field add `ng-change=show_end_date=true;`

and in the to field add `bs-show="show_end_date"`